# UIWebView not playing YouTube videos

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-simulator

Running into an issue where I am trying to play a YouTube video through a custom UIViewController which contains a UIWebView.  All web pages load fine in the UIWebView but if I go to play a YouTube video nothing is displayed.  I can hear the video and the status bar is displayed at the top the screen but I can't see any video.

I've researched this a bit to find that...

-YouTube videos may not play in the simulator so I tried it on my device (iPhone 4 with iOS 4.1) to no avail

-There may be issues when trying to play a YouTube video when tethered and deploying through XCode so I tried deploying to my iPhone and then untethering.  Video still does not play and I get the same results as noted above.

I'm suspicious that a MPMoviePlayer may be getting childed to the UIWebView but the view portion of that movie player is not being set for some reason which is why I'm not seeing it.  Not completely sure about that.

I am seeing alot of threads on this issue but nothing has led me to a solution yet.  If there is any input you can offer it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I Assume you're using Embed Video, i have created HTML file and inserted the Embed video tags and in my web view i use the following:

```
 [WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AboutiPad" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```

it will work for both Simulator and devices this snippet is tested and is being used now, Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to play a youtube video with an https URL?
I've noticed that if I try to embed videos with https, they don't always work on some devices.

I basically used the info from this post: [Embedding YouTube videos on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117617/embedding-youtube-videos-on-ios)

But made sure I ran my URL parameter through the following code before putting it into the HTML template:

```
    NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString:@"https"];
    if (range.length == 5 && range.location == 0) {
        urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"http"];
    }
```