# iOS how to directly play youtube videos without embedding it in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube

I want to add a youtube video play functionality to my iPhone app.
But I dont want to embed it in a UIWebView,

Basically I want to remove an extra view before video is played.
I want a user to see the video as soon as he taps on (say) a UITableViewCell.

Is this possible??

I have seen this post: [Embedding YouTube videos on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117617/embedding-youtube-videos-on-ios)
But that is not the solution I want.

Also if I launch Youtube application directly, users wont be redirected to the app. after video is completed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController. It is a 3rd party YouTube library. https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController

*From their Readme:*

Keep in mind that XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController uses progressive download, so remember that some restrictions apply if you submit your app to the App Store, as stated in HTTP Live Streaming — Requirements for Apps:

> Warning: iOS apps submitted for distribution in the App Store must
>   conform to these requirements.
>
> If your app delivers video over cellular networks, and the video
>   exceeds either 10 minutes duration or 5 MB of data in a five minute
>   period, you are required to use HTTP Live Streaming. (Progressive
>   download may be used for smaller clips.)

Answer (score -1):

I have never used youtube apis, but i suppose you can access the underlying movie file url. If you can (and the video is plain h264) you can stream directly to the device using MPMoviePlayerController and friends.