# YouTube video in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, video, uiwebview, youtube, embed

I have set up a UIWebView to show my YouTube's Channel, I'm using this code

```
[youTube loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/v/user/MyChannel/"]]];
```

This work when I build and go on the simulator but when I want to play a video on my device, the video never show up...

The console say that when I compile with my device

*warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5313e)/Symbols/System/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.webplugin/QuickTime Plugin (file not found).
warning: No copy of QuickTime Plugin.webplugin/QuickTime Plugin found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.*

I think I have to install the QuickTime Plugin ? I don't really know what I have to do..

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You're using a Simulator. Youtube videos are not supported on the simulator. Test yout code out on a device.
Please check this answer on how to embbed youtube videos correctly.
[Embedding YouTube videos on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117617/embedding-youtube-videos-on-ios)

To actually read the channel, I think you can use either the RSS feed for your channel or the [youtube data api](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api) and parse this, than let the user choose the sperate Videos

Comment: it's for show my channel, can I do the same with this ? 
So, in a uiwebview I load my channel and I want to load any video from it..

Comment: I just want to load in a UIWebView my Youtube's channel (not just a video !) and be able to watch them in my own app... 
For the moment, my app can load my channel but can't load them...
Have you an idea to solve that ? :/ 
My console say that QuickTime is missing or something like that..
Thanks

Comment: It's not me ;) But I don't understand how I can setting this up... :(