# Embedding YouTube video into a wall

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube

I have an app, that has a wall, in which there can be text and YouTube links. What I want to do is to detect if that video is from YouTube, that's not hard, but the other part is to play it inside the app, not exiting it. Which I find quite hard to do.

Should I look into UIWebView, or that would only play all the videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open a youtube link in a uiwebview, this will give you the proper experience.

To do this, create a webview and display it modally (or in a navigationController).  Then send the URL request with the youtube link to the webview.  You will then have to either manually or automatically dismiss the webview.

Take a look [YouTube video in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539214/youtube-video-in-uiwebview) and [UIWebView modal YouTube player "Done" button action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959367/uiwebview-modal-youtube-player-done-button-action) .