# Displaying flash-based youtube videos on ios devices

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, flash, uiwebview, youtube

Is it possible to display flashed-based youtube videos on ios devices?
What solution do you use when you decide to embed youtube videos on your app?
Or do I have to give up on all flash-based contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: It is not possible.  There is no way to *run* Flash on iOS yet, and as of last week, Adobe announced it will terminate further development for Flash on mobile devives, so there will never be. And yes, therefore you have to give up Flash-based video on iOS.

YouTube provides HTML5 versions of all videos, so you have an alternative. There a number of posts here on SO that will help you to get started, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117617/embedding-youtube-videos-on-ios).

Comment: Adobe will be supporting the their current version though.. (aka bugs and fixes etc..).  Adobe apparently came to realize that html5 will eventually phase out flash.  Flash is still buggy in android..