# How is Instapaper on iOS embedding YouTube Videos?

Tags: ios, embed, youtube-api, instapaper

I trying to find a good way to embed YouTube Videos in my app. I really like the way Instapaper is embedding them but I can't figure out what YouTube Player is being used.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use the following code to play the youtube videos in the youtube app

```
    NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzUXXXXXXXM&feature=youtube_gdata_player";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

However if you feel you have to play the video inside your application please check following links

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/70282-tutorial-embedding-youtube-vids.html

[Embedding YouTube videos on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117617/embedding-youtube-videos-on-ios)

Hope this helps...  Happy coding..