# youtube video embed in iphone app but giving me white empty box

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube

I am trying to embed youtube video in my app and I am using this function

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:videoView]; }
```

also I am calling like that :

```
[self embedYouTube:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ABkqmqiYEI" frame:CGRectMake(30, 200, 260, 200)];
```

But when I run the app it gives me white empty box .

here is my question : how to make sure that the embed working probably ?

Comment: Does it work if you create an html page and load it in safari?

Comment: no, how to do what are you saying ?

Comment: create a webpage on your web server that contains the same code and open it in safari. You could also do this locally with the simulator

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding YouTube videos on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117617/embedding-youtube-videos-on-ios)

Comment: thank you , i tried in my iphone and it is work probably ..

Comment: did you check on device because simulator cant run youtube videos